# Reverting PHP to 5.2 from 5.3 in Lucid 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, php

I recently upgraded my main development laptop to Lucid. Lucid upgraded PHP to 5.3 and as I'm mainly a PHP developer, this has caused quite a few problems. What's the easiest way to revert back to the the 5.2 series? Googling hasn't found any good solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall php 5.3:

```
sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php5 php5
```

Download this file: http://php.net/get/php-5.2.13.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror

Follow instructions in the *INSTALL* file: *Chapter 2. Installation on Unix systems*

Answer (score 0):

you could "apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php5 php5" and change your sources.list back to karmic, install php (5.2) and change the sources.list back to lucid. remember not to upgrade the package.